# Row's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 2

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below screen image

I have a Apple login in the ui so I need to use this Apple login in IOS only, so I create the below code:

```
Platform.isIOS
                                ? IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                                    constraintWidth:
                                        constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                                    constraintHeight:
                                        constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                                    iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                      ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.apple,
                                      colour: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    iPetIconColor: Colors.black,
                                    iPetFillColor: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                : null
```

I found this error:

```
Row's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 2
```

I tried to handle the problem by add an empty widget as the below code

```
Platform.isIOS
                                ? IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                                    constraintWidth:
                                        constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                                    constraintHeight:
                                        constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                                    iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                      ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.apple,
                                      colour: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    iPetIconColor: Colors.black,
                                    iPetFillColor: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                : SizedBox()
```

but the problem the the look is not good as I need the rest of the buttons to be in the center of the row and this is my Full Row:

```
Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                              constraintWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                              constraintHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                              iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(),
                              iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.google,
                                colour: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              iPetIconColor: Colors.white,
                              iPetFillColor: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                              constraintWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                              constraintHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                              iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(),
                              iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.facebook,
                                colour: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              iPetIconColor: AppConst.kPrimaryWhiteBgColor,
                              iPetFillColor: AppConst.kBlueColor,
                            ),
                            Platform.isIOS
                                ? IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                                    constraintWidth:
                                        constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                                    constraintHeight:
                                        constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                                    iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                      ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.apple,
                                      colour: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    iPetIconColor: Colors.black,
                                    iPetFillColor: Colors.white,
                                  )
                                : SizedBox()
                          ],
                        ),
```

So there's any nice trick for this case :D..

I hope this could be clear enough..

[image: login Screen]

Comment: Instead of SizeBox , just use a widget  like Center()

Comment: @KabirouAgouda I have thought about this solution before but I didn't imagine this is the best one, thanks between for this I have already tried it but didn't work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the better solution for this just make as the below code:

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
                              IPetCustomCircleBtn(
                                constraintWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.13,
                                constraintHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 0.13,
                                iPetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                iPetChildCard: IPetCustomIcon(
                                  ipFontIc: FontAwesomeIcons.apple,
                                  colour: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                iPetIconColor: Colors.black,
                                iPetFillColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you build two rows, 1 with apple login and other without, then  call `Platform.isIOS ? rowWithIos : rowWithoutIos` and if you build widgets for all login types you reduce the repeat code in this two rows.

Comment: I didn't like this solution I am avoiding of repeating code implementation, your solution will be good if I extract the row as a widget class and make constructors with a `List` for the row children :D

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Try adding a height & width to your sizedBox

   ```
        SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0,)
   ```
2. Experiment with

   ```
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: Platform.isIOS ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround 
                                        :  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
            ....
   ```

You can replace mainAxisAlignment as your needs

Comment: thanks for your help :), I have already tried the first  one, but let me try the second way thank you

Comment: I think this solution is near to right but make instead space between make center and add sized box with same same rule